# std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> to Eigen::MatrixXd Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I would like to know whether is there an easier way to solve my problem rather than use a for loop. So here is the situation:

In general, I would like to gather data points from my sensor (the message is of type `Eigen::Vector3d` and I can't change this, because it's a huge framework)

Gathered points should be saved in Eigen `MatrixXd` (in order to process them further as the Matrix in the optimization algorithm), the dimensions apriori of the Matrix are partially unknown, because it depends of me how many measurements I will take  (one dimension is 3 because there are x,y,z coordinates)

For the time being, I created a `std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>` where I collect points by push_back and after I finished collecting points I would like to convert it to `MatrixXd` by using the operation Map .

```
 sensor_input = Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>(sensor_input_vector.data(),3,sensor_input_vector.size());
```

But I have an error and note : no known conversion for argument 1 from `Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>*` to `Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >::PointerArgType {aka double*}`

Can you tell me how I could implement this by using a map function?

Comment: What's wrong with using a for loop?

Comment: I'm just curious/interested, is there an easier way, and I'm assuming map is more efficient that for loop?

Comment: `Map` is the correct way to go here. But you should post an actual [mcve]. `Eigen::Map` is a templated type, so your code above can't compile at all.

Comment: In other languages, map might be more efficient. In C++, it'll all be the same

Comment: Ok, your mcve was just messed up due to not being formated correctly. You need to write `sensor_input_vector[0].data()` instead of `sensor_input_vector.data()`

Comment: chtz, it works, but i don't think I understand why

Comment: @AndrzejReinke If you had added an `@` before my name, I would have gotten a notification. I'll post an answer with some explanations in a moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: You need to write (after making sure that your input is not empty):

```
sensor_input = Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>(sensor_input_vector[0].data(),3,sensor_input_vector.size());
```

The reason is that `Eigen::Map` expects a pointer to the underlying `Scalar` type (in this case `double*`), whereas `std::vector::data()` returns a pointer to the first element inside the vector (i.e., an `Eigen::Vector3d*`).

Now `sensor_input_vector[0].data()` will give you a pointer to the first (`Vector3d`) entry of the first element of your `std::vector`. Alternatively, you could `reinterpret_cast` like so:

```
sensor_input = Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>(reinterpret_cast<double*>(sensor_input_vector.data()),3,sensor_input_vector.size());
```

In many cases you can actually avoid copying the data to a `Eigen::MatrixXd` but instead directly work with the `Eigen::Map`, and instead of `MatrixXd` you can use `Matrix3Xd` to express that it is known at compile time that there are exactly 3 rows:

```
// creating an Eigen::Map has O(1) cost
Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix3Xd> sensor_input_mapped(sensor_input_vector[0].data(),3,sensor_input_vector.size());
// use sensor_input_mapped, the same way you used sensor_input before
```

You need to make sure that the underlying `std::vector` will not get re-allocated while `sensor_input_mapped` is used. Also, changing individual elements of the `std::vector` will change them in the `Map` and vice versa.

Comment: You seem to be assuming `sensor_input_vector[0].data() + sensor_input_vector[0].size()` == `sensor_input_vector[1].data()`. Does Eigen guarantee that?

Comment: @Caleth Yes, for all fixed sized data types this is guaranteed.

Comment: @chtz, your answer does not work if `sensor_input_vector` is a VectorXd (not Vector3d). Do you have any suggestions for dynamic size Eigen vector, VectorXd.

Comment: @JohnPekl If you mean `std::vector<Eigen::VectorXd>`, you cannot map that into an `Eigen::Map`, since the data is not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work:

```cpp
Eigen::MatrixXd sensor_input = Eigen::MatrixXd::Map(sensor_input_vector[0].data(),
 3, sensor_input_vector.size());
```

Since your output will be a matrix of 3 x N (N is the number of 3D vectors), you could use the `Map` function of `Eigen::Matrix3Xd` too:

```cpp
Eigen::Matrix3Xd sensor_input = Eigen::Matrix3Xd::Map(sensor_input_vector[0].data(),
 3, sensor_input_vector.size());
```