# how to map a Eigen::Matrix to std::vector<Eigen::vector>?

Tags: c++, eigen, stdvector

E.g., if I have an `Eigen::MatrixXd` of size 10 columns and 3 rows, how can I alias that to a `std::vector` of 10 elements of `Eigen::Vector3d`?
when I say alias I mean using the same memory block without copying.

I know that I can do the reversed mapping by something like:

```
std::vector<Vector3d> v(10);
...
Map<Matrix<double,3,Dynamic> >  m(v.data().data(), 3, 10);
```

but reversely, if I have an Eigen::Matrix, I tried to convert it to a vector of Eigen::vector but the following code line failed compilation

```
Eigen::Matrix2Xd points;
...
std::vector<Eigen::Vector2d> v_points(points.data()
    Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::vector2d>(points_data()))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> to Eigen::MatrixXd Eigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813340/stdvectoreigenvector3d-to-eigenmatrixxd-eigen)

Comment: no it is not, i want the reversed conversion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible using a custom allocator as described there: [Is it possible to initialize std::vector over already allocated memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917529)

To this end, you'll have to reinterpret it as a `Vector3d*`:

```
Vector3d* buf = reinterpret_cast<Vector3d*>(mat.data());
```

and then pass it to your custom allocator:

```
std::vector<Vector3d, PreAllocator<Vector3d>> my_vec(10, PreAllocator<Vector3d>(buf, 10));
```

Another option would be to wrap it within some views alike `std::vector`, e.g. `gsl::span`:

```
gsl::span<Vector3d> view(buf,mat.cols());
```

In both cases, the `mat` object must stay alive throughout the lifetime of the `std::vector` or `span`.

For completeness, you can also deeply copy it within a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Vector3d> v(10);
Matrix<double,3,Dynamic>::Map(v.data().data(),3,10) = mat;
```

Comment: So you mean `Matrix<double,3,Dynamic>::Map(vec.data().data()) = mat;` deep copies the data in `mat` to `vec`? I read about the documentation of `Map` and seems it does not copy the memory, I am confused here where the deep copy happens...

Comment: The `Map` object only stores a pointer to `vec`'s buffer and the deep copy happens in `operator= `.

Comment: So, I saw this question here with some interesting answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917529/is-it-possible-to-initialize-stdvector-over-already-allocated-memory , would it be possible to implement something like this for Eigen::Matrix using a customized allocator?

Comment: I did not thought about using a custom allocator for that, but yes that's definitely possible, just pass `mat.data()` to your custom allocator!

Comment: @ggael Still could not figure out, can you be more specific? or if you can edit the answer, i will update my question first

Comment: Have you noticed that I edited my answer to include the relevant code snippets, with `PreAllocator` coming from the other answer.

Comment: yep, i edited it because i believe there is a typo. also, You sure i can directly use the PreAllocator class from the post directly? i tried, and there seems to be compilation error...